# Has anyone experienced this message ... Coveo Entreprise Search seems to be unavailable. Please make sure that the service is installed and started

Tags: sitecore

I am getting this message. We just upgraded Coveo for Sitecore to 4.0, now our DEV site is experiencing this message every time we try to do a search or even rebuild the indexes. I have verified that the service is running on the Coveo Server. 
Since, there doesn't seem to be a lot of information on this error, I thought I would try this forum. Our version of Sitecore is 7.2.

"***Coveo Entreprise Search seems to be unavailable. Please make sure that the service is installed and started***."

Comment: Have you checked your config settings to make sure they are correct, haven't been reset or overwritten by the upgrade?

Comment: Thank you for your response ... I am hoping to scrutinize these config files today.

Comment: Have you upgraded Coveo Enterprise Search and the Coveo Search API at the same time as your Coveo for Sitecore upgrade? This is required.